# Python read() not showing ouput

Tags: python

I am running this python program and its reading but not showing any output. I tried so many times but nothing working.While its working fine with other function so whats the problem in `read()` function.

[image: 1]

Comment: You can try my answer. Make sure you provide exact path to the file

Comment: Click on the ouput tab just before terminal.

Comment: @Raviv007 can you also leave the code in a snippet instead of as a picture and perhaps only show the output in a picture, so its more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Also can you once show perhaps some part of the text file you are trying to read so we can know the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is something in your 123.txt file.

Comment: I already added texts in 123.txt but still its not showing

Comment: Maybe you didn't save the file.

Comment: VSCode need to save manually unless you modify settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).